# insert multiple entries in database using a loop issue

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, php

**Update**
i have fix the first problem by changing the strectures in sending datas to database, now my problem is that when i select multiple choices and click submit only one of the choices is updated in database (exactly the first one ordering by id) my new Code is belew my old code, by the way i have add

```
echo $cam;
```

to verfy if its looping correctly and yes it does, the only issue is that in database it dont update all the choices entren only one of it

**My orginal post**

> I'm trying to update a custom database table for my WordPress plugin.
>       I'm firstly getting the roles from my table, then displaying it using a form. This works fine. When I check the boxes it updates in
>   the database, but when I uncheck them, it doesn't update at all - and
>   I get this error message:
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\wamp\www\wp_test\wp-content\plugins\Data\settings.php on line 52
>
> Here's my code. Where am I going wrong?

```
<?php 
$roles=get_editable_roles();

global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix. "Author_detailed_repport";
?>

<h3>Settings Page</h3>
<h4>Add/Remove a role from filter list</h4>
<p>This setting allow you to add/remove roles from the filter<br />
  list, here down a list of all the roles existing in your website, all<br />
  you have to do is to check/uncheck wich you wanna add/rmove from filter list</p>
<form action="<?php $_REQUEST['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
  <?php 
require_once('../wp-config.php');
$i=0;
foreach($roles as $role)
{

     $rom=$role['name'];
     $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM  ".$table_name." WHERE role= '".$rom."'" );
     if ($results==NULL)
            {$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 
                                  'role' => $role['name'],
                                  'statut' => '', 
                                  'post_number' => '', 
                                  'activate' => ''
                                   ));
            }?>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="<?php echo $i+1 ;?>" <?php checked($results[0]->statut, $i+1); ?> />
 <input type="hidden" name="ww" value="0">
   <?php 


 ?>
  <label>
  <?php echo $results[0]->role;?></label><br />

  <?php $i++; } ?>
  <input type="submit" value="save" name="saveme" />
</form>
<?php 


if(isset($_POST['saveme']))
{
    $cats=$_POST['cat'];
    foreach($cats as $cam)
    {
        if(isset($cam))
        {
        $wpdb->update( $table_name, array( 
                                  'statut' => $cam 
                                   ),array('ADR_id' => $cam),array('%d'));}
        else
        {
             $wpdb->update( $table_name, array( 
                                  'statut' => '0' 
                                   ),array('ADR_id' => $cam),array('%d'));

            }
    }

}

?>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<?php 
$roles=get_editable_roles();

global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix. "Author_detailed_repport";
?>

<h3>Settings Page</h3>
<h4>Add/Remove a role from filter list</h4>
<p>This setting allow you to add/remove roles from the filter<br />
  list, here down a list of all the roles existing in your website, all<br />
  you have to do is to check/uncheck wich you wanna add/rmove from filter list</p>
<form action="<?php $_REQUEST['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend><strong>List of activated roles</strong></legend>
<ul>
  <?php 
require_once('../wp-config.php');

$i=0;
foreach($roles as $role)
{

     $rom=$role['name'];
     $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM  ".$table_name." WHERE role= '".$rom."'" );
     if ($results==NULL)
            {$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 
                                  'role' => $role['name'],
                                  'statut' => '', 
                                  'post_number' => '', 
                                  'activate' => ''
                                   ));
            }?>

<?php if($results[0]->ADR_id==$results[0]->statut) {?>

<li><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $results[0]->ADR_id*2; ?>" name="rm[]" /><label><?php echo $results[0]->role;?></label></li>

<?php }} ?>
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="remove" name="remove" />
</fieldset>
</form>
<form action="<?php $_REQUEST['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend><strong>List of deactivated roles</strong></legend>
<ul>
  <?php 
require_once('../wp-config.php');

$i=0;
foreach($roles as $role)
{

     $rom=$role['name'];
     $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM  ".$table_name." WHERE role= '".$rom."'" );
     if ($results==NULL)
            {$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 
                                  'role' => $role['name'],
                                  'statut' => '', 
                                  'post_number' => '', 
                                  'activate' => ''
                                   ));
            }?>

<?php if($results[0]->ADR_id!=$results[0]->statut) {?>

<li><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $results[0]->ADR_id; ?>" name="ad[]" /><label><?php echo $results[0]->role;?></label></li>

<?php }} ?>
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Add" name="add" />
</fieldset>
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['remove']))
    {   if(isset($_POST['rm'])){
        $cam=implode(",",$_POST['rm']);
        $wpdb->update( $table_name, array( 
                                  'statut' => $cam 
                                   ),array('ADR_id' => $cam/2),array('%d'));
        echo $cam;
            }
     else{
         $cam='';exit();}
    }
        if(isset($_POST['add']))
    {   if(isset($_POST['ad'])){
        $cam=implode(",",$_POST['ad']);
        echo $cam;
        $wpdb->update( $table_name, array( 
                                  'statut' => $cam 
                                   ),array('ADR_id' => $cam),array('%d'));}
        else{
         $cam='';exit();
         }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your variable `$roles` , either contains no value or is not an array, foreach only process an array/object.

Comment: nope that variable work fine, the problem is only that when i uncheck my chckbox it dont update in the database

Comment: did you tried debugging by printing $cat or $_POST['cat'], after un-checking the check box, i believe you are not getting proper data on post back after un-check. @MessiAdrinho

Comment: yeah thats true, what i'm trying to do is that when i uncheck checkbox it will send the value 0 to update the value already exist in datatabe @bhupendraosd

Comment: You have 2 foreach loops. Am I correct that your "line 52" error is for the second one - foreach ( $cats as $cam ) ? The error is to be expected - IF no checkbox is checked. Because, in that case, $_POST['cat'] is not set. Could this be the problem?

Comment: yeah i have fix that already but the principal problem i'm having here is how can i send a value when box is unchecked @Jeff Cohan

Comment: Show us some rows from the table. And maybe a screen shot of your form. Then I think we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If **no role** is checked when you submit, the $_POST['cat'] will not be set. That will trigger the "invalid argument supplied for foreach" error. In the beginning of your

```
if ( isset($_POST['saveme']) )
```

structure, I'd put:

```
if ( !isset($_POST['cat']) ) {
  // code to update db value to 0
}
```